# MYSQL ON DUPLICATE KEY Query problem

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

Having a problem with this query, anyone know the problem?

```
INSERT INTO options
  (grouptogether) 
VALUES 
  ('0') 
WHERE userid = '2' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE grouptogether = '0';

INSERT INTO options 
  (grouptogether) 
VALUES 
  ('0') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE grouptogether = '0' 
WHERE userid = '2';
```

I tried both combinations of moving the where clause, but that doesn't seem to do it.

Comment: [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) -- there is no `WHERE` clause in the `ON DUPLICATE ...` syntax.

Comment: Just a tip -- you do not want to put single quotes around values for numeric columns. `userid = 2`, not `userid = '2'`. A number inside a string is not always equal to the number you expect when you force an interpreter to cast it to the correct type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`INSERT` queries do not have `WHERE` clauses. In an `INSERT INTO...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` query the row which gets updated is the row in which there was a key collision; you do not need to specify the row by a `WHERE` clause.

You probably meant to do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO options
  (userid, grouptogether) 
VALUES 
  (2, '0') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE grouptogether = VALUES(grouptogether)
```